# AVPlayer Support 2.35:1 Cinematic Ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer

I have used AVPlayer in iOS to play HLS content. Some media contents are in cinematic ratio 2.35:1 and edges of the contents are cut off.

I tired with videoGravity with all possible values like AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill,AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect and AVLayerVideoGravityResize, but no luck.

Any idea on how to support media with cinematic ratio( 2.35:1) in AVPlayer in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a content issue so no AVPlayer code change